# Reply using newComponseActionResponseBuilder crashes gmail android app

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

The reply action of the add-on works fine in google chrome. But creates a draft and crashes the gmail app in android. However remaining features of the add on remains unaffected. Do any one experience similar issues ?

```js
function renderComposeMail(e) {
    // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
    // a reply to be drafted.
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

    // Creates a draft reply.
    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var draft = message.createDraftReply('A logo',
        {
            htmlBody: "Kitten! <img src='cid:logo'/>",
            attachments: [
              UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/2d/a0/dc/2da0dc7b-acf5-0fad-0093-0065cd89ff7b/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-85-220-0-6.png/246x0w.jpg')
                  .getBlob()
            ],
            inlineImages: {
              "logo": UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple118/v4/2d/a0/dc/2da0dc7b-acf5-0fad-0093-0065cd89ff7b/AppIcon-1x_U007emarketing-85-220-0-6.png/246x0w.jpg')
                           .getBlob()
            }
        }
    );
 
    var card = CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder().setGmailDraft(draft)
    return card.build();
}
```

I've added it as an
[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110564375)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the sample code snippet in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/compose-action-response?hl=vi).

```
var composeActionResponse = CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
    .setGmailDraft(GmailApp.createDraft("recipient", "subject", "body"))
    .build();
```

Also, if you're having an error, do troubleshooting an it's an important part of the development process. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) for some techniques that can help you find, understand, and debug errors in your scripts.

Comment: Even the above code crashes gmail app. Nevertheless, thanks for your tip. I guess , I have to log this as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like its a bug outside of your control. I would recommend logging it as an issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:325133%2B%20status:open%20type:bug . There are quite a few issues outstanding for the add-ons we have logged several bugs ourselves.

Comment: Yep. It is a bug outside of my control.